# bidirectional OneToOne Mapping : From Entity to subclass and from superclass to Entity?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to establish a tricky bidirectional OneToOne mapping in hibernate. I got the following classes :

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent {
     @OneToOne
     private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
}
@Entity
public class Child1 extends Parent{}

@Entity
public class Child2 extends Parent{}

@Entity
public class AnotherEntity {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "anotherEntity")
    private Child1 child1;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "anotherEntity")
    private Child2 child2;
}
```

The problem here is when I'm launching the application : I got the following message :

```java
org.hibernate.MappingException: property [anotherEntity] not found on entity [Child1]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getRecursiveProperty(PersistentClass.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getReferencedProperty(PersistentClass.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1614)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1727)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1471)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

One obvious solution would be to move the `anotherEntity` field to `Child1` and `Child2`, but it would mean lose the link from `Parent` to `AnotherEntity`.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace?  I am having trouble reproducing the error.

Comment: Full exception stacktrace added. Additionnaly I'm using Spring for configuring hibernate, and it's a webapplication in a tomcat server, but i'm don't think it's relevant

Comment: I found the problem could come from the inheritance. When I'm removing the line `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` and switch to a single table inheritance strategy (the default one), I have no more problem.

Comment: I was not very clear in my last comment, but changing the strategy is not a possible solution, so I'm still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't (with Hibernate).

First, it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish with the example given.  You have specified that you want `AnotherEntity` to have two properties of type `Child1`.  I am guessing that you actually want one of each, `Child1` and `Child2`.  Additionally, you are using the same `mappedBy = "anotherEntity"` on both properties, do you really mean you want two references on Parent to anotherEntity?  In either case this helps illustrate the problem with this type of situation:

You have specified `InheritanceType.JOINED`, which means that the foreign key for `Parent` -> `AnotherEntity` lives on whatever table the `Parent` class is mapped to.  Hibernate cannot distinguish between your two subtypes in this case, it would have to depend solely on the type specified in your Java class -- this could definitely lead to problems.

Apparently, other JPA providers may support this behavior (but you can see why Hibernate chose not to, and why you would need to be careful with it).  For reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/why-onetomany-does-not-work-with-inheritance-in-hibernate) similar SO question and various discussions on Hibernate forums/JIRA:

- [[ANN-558] @OneToMany(mappedBy="") can not recognize properties in parent classes](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-558)
- [[HHH-4233] cant bind a child using mappedby relating to a parent attribute(polymorphism)](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4233)
- [Hibernate complains about missing property?](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2380570)

Comment: Okay, thank for your response. I've done without it until now, and I will continue.