# Hibernate not links entities to Generic

Tags: java, hibernate

I have class Template:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "templates")
public class Template extends AbstractEntity {

    private List<AbstractField> fields;
}
```

It composes from fields, and I get any like quiz.

I have entities, whick inherits AbstractField:

```
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractField extends AbstractEntity {

    private FieldType fieldType;
    private String title;
    private Template template;
}
```

As we see, we have an abstract class of field (checkbox, radio button etc.), & all fields extends this abstract field, like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "field_checkbox")
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class CheckBoxField extends AbstractField {

    private Boolean selection = false;
}
```

I need to link fields with one-to-many dependency. I did it with this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appeal_templates")
public class Template<F extends AbstractField> extends AbstractEntity {

    private List<F> fields;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "template")
    public List<F> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

As we see, I decided to do it with generic. And I get exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property
>   ru.model.representation.appeal.template.Template.fields has an unbound
>   type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue
>   or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an
>   explicit @Type

As I understand, Hibernate not allow to map to generic. But I plan to store many types of fields, extended AbstractField. What to do?

Comment: You can use  `List< AbstractField > fields`

Comment: I tried, result is the same exception.

Comment: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Comment: Didn't see you have two different tables, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do with different tables for subclasses. [Check this comment why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448/4916156)

What you can do is to define single table inheritance type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fields")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractField extends AbstractEntity {

    private FieldType fieldType;
    private String title;
    private Template template;
}
```

And then you can use `List<AbstractField> fields` in `Template` class.